# Seemingly random ISO files won't copy to USB HDD

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, ntfs, iso-image

I have had a handful of iso files from different sources; different vendors, custom bootdisks, with entirely different contents, and of varying sizes that simply won't copy to my external HDD.  I have confirmed that the external HDD is formatted using the NTFS filesystem. It's a 2TB drive with about 933GB of available free space.  The iso files are generally a couple of GB.

The most recent failure is with an iso file that's almost exactly 1GB in size.  This was with a custom CentOS 7 live bootdisk.  Another instance was with VMware's NSX for vSphere installation ISO.

It'll start to copy, stall somewhere in the middle, and then eventually timeout and fail.

This has only occurred with iso files specifically.  Additionally, there are many other iso files that have successfully transferred to the drive.

I should also clarify that I'm not copying the ISO files to the drive with the intention of booting my system from them.  I'm simply archiving the ISO file for future use.

I'm wondering if this is a sign of a failing drive.  The drive is fairly old; at least 3-4 years old.  I've saved a backup of the drive just to be safe.  Should I start shopping for a new drive?  Would something as simple as using the Windows "Optimize and defragment drive" or "Error checking" tools fix this?

Comment: Is the drive going to sleep? Yes run chkdsk on the drive, also have a look at the SMART data on the disk.

Comment: Are you able to save the file, that fails to copy to the USB HDD, to another location on the disk as a test?  I have never heard of a copy operation "timing out" though

Comment: @Ramhound Wow, now that is surprising.  I was indeed able to copy it to a different destination folder on the drive.  Why on earth would that make a difference?

Comment: Which disk did you copy it to exactly? I was suggesting the same disk the ISO was already on.

Comment: @Ramhound It was stored on my internal C: drive; on the Desktop.  But I had been trying to copy it to my External USB HDD and it was failing.  Thus, the reason I posted this question.  Per your suggestion, I copied it to a different destination folder than I had previously been specifying on the External USB HDD, and this time it succeeded.  I should also mention that once it was copied to the External USB HDD, I then moved it to the original folder that that I been specifying previously and it moved successfully.

Comment: @dutsnekcirf - I have no explanation for the copying working.  But I also have never known a copy to "timeout" either.